# Which shell should be used for Bazel under Windows 10

Tags: powershell, bazel, msys2

Usually, on Windows, I use PowerShell (default shell) to call a Bazel command such as `bazel build`. As far as I understand Bazel makes use of MSYS2 to call and execute commands such as `curl`, `zip` or `git` for instance. Therefore, I wonder if I should use the MSYS2 bash terminal instead of PowerShell. Can there be any problems when using Powershell instead of the MSYS2 bash terminal? Or doesn’t it matter?

Comment: They are similar.  It's up to you.  Bash might handle doublequotes better if you often use them with bazel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current master there was recently an [update of the documentation exactly about this issue](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html):

> As of 2020-01-15, we do not recommend running Bazel from bash – either
>   from MSYS2 shell, or Git Bash, or Cygwin, or any other Bash variant.
>   While Bazel may work for most use cases, some things are broken, like
>   interrupting the build with Ctrl+C from MSYS2). Also, if you choose to
>   run under MSYS2, you need to disable MSYS2’s automatic path
>   conversion, otherwise MSYS will convert command line arguments that
>   look like Unix paths (e.g. //foo:bar) into Windows paths. See this
>   StackOverflow answer for details.

Comment: i mean i dont get this part. Isnt the installation document asking us to make use of MSYS2. why is it needed in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As its mentioned [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6462#issuecomment-450860881) by developers of bazel, using MSYS or MSYS2 is the best choice. Personally I prefer MSYS* over cmd or PowerShell for any thing.

Comment: Thanks to Vertexwahn [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783482/7264131), I assume mine is out of date